# Warning Message: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: php

```
class Forum_model extends CI_Model {

/**
 * __construct function.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper(array('url'));
}

function badfilter($text)
{
    $filter_terms = array('\bass(es|holes?)?\b', '\bshit(e|ted|ting|ty|head)\b','\bf[ ]*u[ ]*c[ ]*k[]*\b','\bf+u+c+k+\b');
            $filtered_text = $text;
            foreach($filter_terms as $word)
             {
              $match_count = preg_match_all('/' . $word . '/i', $text, $matches);
              for($i = 0; $i < $match_count; $i++)
             {
              $bwstr = trim($matches[0][$i]);
              $filtered_text = preg_replace('/\b' . $bwstr . '\b/', str_repeat("*", strlen($bwstr)), $filtered_text);
             }
             }
       return $filtered_text;
    }

/**
 * create_forum function.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param string $title
 * @param string $description
 * @return bool
 */
public function create_forum($title, $description) {

    $data = array(
        'title'       => $title,
        'slug'        => strtolower(url_title($title)),
        'description' => $description,
        'created_at'  => date('Y-m-j H:i:s'),
    );

    return $this->db->insert('forums', $data);

}

/**
 * get_forum_id_from_forum_slug function.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param string $slug
 * @return int
 */
public function get_forum_id_from_forum_slug($slug) {

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('forums');
    $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
    return $this->db->get()->row('id');

}

/**
 * get_topic_id_from_topic_slug function.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param string $topic_slug
 * @return int
 */
public function get_topic_id_from_topic_slug($topic_slug) {

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('topics');
    $this->db->where('slug', $topic_slug);
    return $this->db->get()->row('id');

}

/**
 * get_forums function.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @return array of objects
 */
public function get_forums() {

    $text=$this->db->get('forums')->result();
            $this->badfilter($text);

}
}
```

the above code  is of the controller of a project file and it is still after some correction also showing array to string conversion error .
kindly see the above code

Comment: So what is in the parameter `$text` I would hazzard a guess its an array!

Comment: no its the text from the post section which the user will enter and it will be fetched from database . $filter_terms is the array ,you can now see the full code

Comment: _“no its the text”_ – well PHP begs to differ. _Verify_ it, by making a debug output of the value using `var_dump`, that will show you what type it _actually_ is.

Comment: You call `badfilter($text)` from `get_forums()` that looks like a database access which is most likely to return an array even if there is only one result. CHECK WHAT `$text` ACTUALLY IS

Comment: Trust the error message _PHP does not just make them up when it gets bored_

Comment: $text it is string of array

Comment: Do you mean an array of strings